set up a bmp280 on a raspberry 3b
I am trying to set up a bmp280 preassure sensor that is on a JOY-It explorer 700 with a raspberry 3b. My problem is that when I try to install the necessary libraries from github:
https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_BMP280.git
https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_Bundle.git
I get the following error:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement adafruit-circuitpython-bmp280 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for adafruit-circuitpython-bmp280

I am using raspbian (bookworm) version 12. Does someone know how to fix this?
I tried to download the libraries using sudo pip3 which resultet in the following error:
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> The Python environment under /usr is managed externally, and may not be
    manipulated by the user. Please use specific tooling from the distributor of
    the Python installation to interact with this environment instead.


note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.

After that i tried to use a virtual enviroment and pip which resulted in the error I described above.

What version of Python is installed on your Pi?

I haver Python 3.11.2

@OneCricketeer I used 'source venv/bin/activate'. After that I followed the isntructions in the manual: link

Did you update latest bookworm?
